# Magento - Install script not running (but record add to core_resource correctly)

Tags: magento, module, installation

So, I'm trying to run a setup script with my module. (Magento 1.7)
I have this is my modules config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sulman_Custompermissions>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Sulman_Custompermissions>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sulman_Custompermissions</module>
                </setup>
            </mymodule_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

This my file structure for the install script:
    /app/code/local/Sulman/Custompermissions/sql/mymodule_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php

Then in my install-1.0.0.0.php script simply runs this:

```
die('here');
```

The issue is that the install script never seems to get run (nothing dies).
**BUT There IS** a row correctly inserted in to the core_resource table...
Any clues? Thanks

(p.s. if there is a record in the core_resource table it is removed before I try to run the script)

Comment: How are you triggering the setup script workflow?

Comment: By refreshing the homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fact that your module's config XML is being merged in (hence the record in `core_resource`), and assuming that the XML in your post is a copy of that content, there are three possibilities:

1. Filesystem hierarchy: you have a typo in your filename, folders, or incorrect folder structure
2. Permissions: PHP cannot `include()` the contents of your file
3. There is duplicate config.xml which specifies a different subdirectory, and this file is actually not being merged.

Solutions:

1. Look, look, look
2. Check permissions, test the script directly
3. `grep`, break the config XML in the file in which you are working, and/or dump the config XML for the xpaths in question:

   ```
   echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Sulman_Custompermissions/version');
   echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/mymodule_setup/setup/module');
   ```

Comment: Ahhh! You were right. It turned out it was a case issue in etc/modules/Sulman_Custompermissions.xml....Magento still amazes me that something so seemingly unrelated can cause some things to work and some things not to work! Oh well. Lesson learned. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your config.xml to


    
        
            1.0.0.0

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Sulman_Custompermissions</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

and change the install script file name to `mysql4-install-1.0.0.0.php` and delete the entry from `core_resource` table and clear the cache and check....

Comment: *mysql4-* prefix is deprecated in CE1.7 and connection is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your config.xml names the module as it appears in your sql directory.  For me, I had sql->customizations_setup and this worked fine locally with capital letters like so:

```
    <Customizations_setup>
      <setup>
        <module>AMI_Customizations</module>
        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
      </setup>
      <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
      </connection>
    </Customizations_setup>
```

But this only worked because my local machine is case insensitive.  My production (linux) server is case sensitive and it would create the entry in core_resource ok, but from there it wouldn't create the db entries until I made the xml match my directory name like so:

```
    <customizations_setup>
      <setup>
        <module>AMI_Customizations</module>
        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
      </setup>
      <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
      </connection>
    </customizations_setup>
```